# Unable to restore NuGet Package: "Failed to find api location for area: nuget id: 9D3A4E8E"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget

I am unable to publish new packages to (or restore packages from) my own NuGet Feed in Azure DevOps .  It started a few days ago and, since I have created a brand new feed (out of curiosity). Still, it fails with the same error:

> Failed to find api location for area: nuget id:
>   9D3A4E8E-2F8F-4AE1-ABC2-B461A51CB3B3

```
2019-05-27T22:09:46.8693807Z ##[section]Starting: dotnet push (Common)
2019-05-27T22:09:46.8802338Z ==============================================================================
2019-05-27T22:09:46.8802573Z Task         : .NET Core
2019-05-27T22:09:46.8802607Z Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command. For package commands, supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Package Management and MyGet.
2019-05-27T22:09:46.8802660Z Version      : 2.151.1
2019-05-27T22:09:46.8802692Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-05-27T22:09:46.8802724Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832194)
2019-05-27T22:09:46.8802931Z ==============================================================================
2019-05-27T22:09:47.4837790Z [command]C:\windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
2019-05-27T22:09:47.4924880Z Active code page: 65001
2019-05-27T22:09:47.4964761Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2019-05-27T22:09:47.5770818Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2019-05-27T22:09:50.7225430Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2019-05-27T22:09:50.7673768Z ##[warning]Can\'t find loc string for key: Warning_SessionCreationFailed
2019-05-27T22:09:50.7683040Z ##[warning]Warning_SessionCreationFailed {}
2019-05-27T22:09:52.3193091Z ##[error]Error: Error: Failed to find api location for area: nuget id: 9D3A4E8E-2F8F-4AE1-ABC2-B461A51CB3B3
2019-05-27T22:09:52.3194182Z ##[error]Packages failed to publish
2019-05-27T22:09:52.3294148Z ##[section]Finishing: dotnet push (Common)
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to restore NuGet Package: “Failed to find api location for area: nuget id: 9D3A4E8E”

The reason for the above error is a wrong specification of the URL of the service to use.

So, to resolve this issue, please try to double check if the source of nuget feed is correct.

If the source of nuget feed is correct and this issue is also occurred on the other nuget feed(which is worked before.), you can try to delete the brand new feed, then check if this issue is resolved.

If this issue only occurred on the brand new feed, please try to check if your feed configured correctly and check if the agent has any proxy setting.

Check the ticket [VSTS - Cannot Push Nuget Package to VSTS Package Feed from Private Agent Behind Web Proxy](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/330227/vsts-cannot-push-nuget-package-to-vsts-package-fee.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have not tried deleting the existing feed. However I have created a new one instead and got the same issue. As far as I can tell, it is failing because of an Internal Server Error when the Restore Task is trying to reach the NuGet Feed: `{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your Azure DevOps Server administrator.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.AzureClientIPRestrictedException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server","typeKey":"AzureClientIPRestrictedException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3007}`

Comment: Even after deleting all the feeds and creating a brand new one, it still fails for the same reason...